# Why my BroadcastReceiver receives the intent "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" multiple time however i performed only SCREEN_OFF one time?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-source, screen-off

- I have an android service Running. In this service, i have a BroadcastReceiver which is registred within the intentFilter :
  filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
  filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
- I make the registration in the onStartCommand() method, and the unregistration into the onDestroy().
- When i perform a screen on/off, my receiver recieves well the intents but many times, like this :

01-25 15:38:02.389  1941  1941 D InternetConnectionCheck: ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received
01-25 15:38:02.391  1941  1941 I InternetConnectionCheck: EventsReceiver.onReceive() android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
01-25 15:38:02.391  1941  1941 D InternetConnectionCheck: ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received
01-25 15:38:02.396  1941  1941 I InternetConnectionCheck: EventsReceiver.onReceive() android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
01-25 15:38:02.396  1941  1941 D InternetConnectionCheck: ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received
01-25 15:38:02.400  1941  1941 I InternetConnectionCheck: EventsReceiver.onReceive() android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
01-25 15:38:02.400  1941  1941 D InternetConnectionCheck: ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received
01-25 15:38:02.402  1941  1941 I InternetConnectionCheck: EventsReceiver.onReceive() android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
01-25 15:38:02.402  1941  1941 D InternetConnectionCheck: ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received
01-25 15:38:02.404  1941  1941 I InternetConnectionCheck: EventsReceiver.onReceive() android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON

- For your informations, i have registered the receiver only one time in onStartCommand() as i described above.
- Can anyone help me to solve this problem please ?

As a work arround to solve the problem, i am using a counter to check if the intent is received for the first time or not.

Comment: Does it happen on one device only ? Have you seen this behaviour on the android emulator?

Comment: hi, sorry for being late, i solved my problem because i registred my receiver in onStartCommand() method, and unfortunately there many other services that can start my service when i have the receiver